# Google media advertising как прикрутить? (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3

На ютубе когда смотришь фильмы часто появляется реклама. Как рекламу выдернуть отдельно и показывать в своем проекте as3? Видел, что такое возможно, например, вот..

http://www.flashplayer.ru/play_11389.php

показывается сначала реклама, а потом уже игра..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, всё это извращения - за которые можно получить бан.
Чтобы получать деньги за рекламу достаточно в личном кабинете выбрать размер банера с размером видео.

[image: размер банера]

И так же есть галочка: мультимедиа, или только текст. Нажимаем мультимедиа. И будет показываться видео в больших по размеру банерах.